# how to resample dataframe in every 5 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of a month excluding Saturday and Sunday, which was logged every 1 minute.

```
                         v1         v2  
2017-04-03 09:14:00     35.7       35.4  
2017-04-03 09:15:00     34.7       34.4
2017-04-03 09:16:00     28.1       28.5
2017-04-03 09:17:00     28.3       28.2
2017-04-03 09:18:00     28.5       28.3
2017-04-03 09:19:00     28.6       28.1
2017-04-03 09:20:00     28.7       28.4
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-03 16:25:00     80.7       80.6
2017-04-03 16:26:00     82.5       82.3
2017-04-03 16:27:00     81.6       81.1
2017-04-03 16:28:00     82.7       82.4
2017-04-03 16:29:00     81.7       81.5
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-04 09:14:00     24.3       24.2  
2017-04-04 09:15:00     25.6       25.5
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-04 16:29:00     67.0       67.2
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 09:14:00     31.7       31.4  
2017-04-28 09:15:00     31.5       31.0
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 16:29:00     33.2       33.5
```

How to resample my data to get the first value and last value with every 5min value as well for each day. No statistics like sum, mean etc should happen. `df.groupby(df.index.date).resample('5T').first()` miss the last few values and the start value

Desired output:

```
                        v1         v2
2017-04-03 09:14:00     35.7       35.4  
2017-04-03 09:15:00     34.7       34.4  
2017-04-03 09:20:00     42.1       43.4
      ...                ..         ..
2017-04-03 16:25:00     80.7       80.6
2017-04-03 16:29:00     82.7       82.6
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-04 09:14:00     24.3       24.2
2017-04-04 09:15:00     25.6       25.5
2017-04-04 09:20:00     82.7       82.6
      ...                ..         ..
2017-04-04 16:25:00     69.7       69.6
2017-04-04 16:29:00     70.2       70.6
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 09:14:00     31.7       31.4 
2017-04-28 09:15:00     31.7       31.4 
2017-04-28 09:20:00     32.8       33.0
      ...               ...        ...
2017-04-28 16:25:00     32.7       32.6
2017-04-28 16:29:00     33.0       30.7
```